# pgadmin4 : Unable to connect to local server

Tags: docker, centos, pgadmin

I've installed a dpage/pgadmin4(`port:5050`) on my vmware centos8 from Docker.

And my database postgis(`version:11.2-1`,`port:5432`) also run on docker.

Now I can connect my postgis by using navicat but pdadmin4 not works.

I've got this:

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Permission denied Is the server running on host "172.17.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

or:

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Permission denied Is the server running on host "xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx"(centos ip) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I tried ways from `stackoverflow` but not work.

Comment: How you run the `dpage/pgadmin4` container?

Comment: Did you Change `listen_address localhost to *` and modified `pg_hba.conf` file?

Comment: @Adiii `docker run -d -p 5433:80 --restart=always --name pgadmin4 -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=xxx -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=xxx dpage/pgadmin4:latest` Is this right?

Comment: @Thirumal Yes , I did.  By copying the file out of the container and then modified it .